# How can I count the number of times the user clicks on the X button in my Java program?

Tags: java

I am building a UI in eclipse. How would I make it so it could count how many times the user click the X button? I have tried using WindowListeners and ActionListeners, but I cant make them work and I may have used them wrong.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class NewWindowTest {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello!");
    
    
    public void windowAction(WindowEvent e) {

        //How do I make it count how many times the user clicks on the X to close the window?
        
        int numClicks = 0;
        numClicks++;
        
        if (numClicks>10); {
            displayMessage("Just stop."); }
}
    private void displayMessage(String string) {

    }
    NewWindowTest(){
        
        label.setBounds(0,0,100,50);
        label.setFont(new Font(null,Font.PLAIN,25));
        
        frame.add(label);
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(420,420);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: 1) Define "numClicks" as an instance variable in your class (not a local variable) 2) Clicking on the "X" button will generate a `windowClosing` event.  You handle this event in the WindowListener and increment the "numClicks" variable. The listener needs to be added to the frame. Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. There is a section on "Writing Event Listeners" to get you started. 3) Also, don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The tutorial has a section on layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an event listener to the JFrame object:

```
...
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
var closeButtonClickCounter = 0;
...
frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        closeButtonClickCounter++;      
    }
});
```